# Exporting a command-line tool project from Xcode

Tags: c, xcode

How  do I export a command-line tool (in C) project from Xcode?
(Xcode 5 on Mac OS X)

Comment: What's "export"? Oh, and it's spelled "command".

Comment: Use a builder like [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Comment: basile can you explain to me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just right click on the executable in the Xcode project and select "Show In Finder" to navigate to the compiled program. Not sure what else you're interested in.

[image]

Comment: thanks but its doesn't allow me to do it: http://tinypic.com/r/25k4qk5/5

Comment: Did you compile the project?

Comment: I did it, thank you very much. but one more question can I run it on windows?

Comment: Umm... Maybe? The executable itself will only work on Unix-systems (Assuming this is pure C with no system APIs). The source of course should be able to be compiled using a Windows compiler, again assuming you used pure C libraries.

Comment: I am using windows 8 in what app should I open it couse it asking for one

Comment: You should recompile your project in Windows if you want it to run in Windows. I would start with a Windows compiler.

Comment: This doesn't work if you need to dynamically link against any frameworks, or use any other bundled resources